# In unix arcitecture what is use of POSIX related with c

Tags: c, ubuntu

how can i use POSIX header files in system programming?
    i used   in C. what are other header files i can used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX is a standard implemented by Unix-like systems to give code portability between similar systems. You include their headers like you do any other C header. These headers should be available in the libraries on your Unix-like machine. You can then have access to the data structures in them.

Here is a (partial?) list of POSIX headers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library

Hopefully this helps. Your question is very poorly worded.

Answer (score 2):

Two good resources for calling system functions in Unix are the [Unix Version 3 Standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/toc.htm) and the [Unix Version 2 Standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/toc.htm). I use them routinely for writing portable code.